# not more than 16 sessions are running in parallel in oracle

Tags: multithreading, oracle, session, weblogic

I have batch program that internally is run in multi-threading. The threads are divided via Weblogic server, and the max-bean size is set to 25.
I have 32 CPU's in my instance and enough memory too.

But, when i run my batch, though i see 25 sessions connected, i see only 16 sessions to be ACTIVE.
The rest of the sessions are INACTIVE and they turn ACTIVE only after the first 16 threads are completed. I don't see any wait events too.
All these sessions/threads make use the same set of tables, but don't lock any records because of the unique thread value.

Any ideas/recommendations to run all the 25 sessions in a single go would be helpful.

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Do you have [resource manager limits](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dbrm001.htm#ADMIN11854) in place? Do you see any waiting on the WebLogic side, if there's nothing obvious on the database side?

Comment: start with select inst_id, state, event, count(*)
from gv$session
where username = 'youruser'
group by inst_id, state, event
order by inst_id, state, event; and show the results, while the runs is active.